# Show All Friends List

Tags: list, show

> http://www.soundclick.com/members/default.cfm?member=Ally+Byrd&content=Friends

anyway to show all member list...maybe like edited source with firebug,etc?
I want to grab all user list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php cURL to iterate through all paginated pages (see how the URL is formed using GET) then you can access to every HTML result using XPath functionality.

I'm afraid there is no way to achieve this with javascript (firebug) since pagination isn't built on Ajax.